# Wpf withing transparent grid with opacity = "0.32" Assign Background Color/Image to Buttons and TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Grid with opacity = "0.32" its good working fine but now i want to add some controls like *textboxes* and *button* with some *background solid color* but it also gets the same opacity ration that i don't need here.  Any help please??  Thanks in advance.

```
<Grid Margin="0,1,0,2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
      Background="#06090b" Opacity="0.25">
  <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Content="Sign in" Foreground="White" 
          Margin="40,264,40,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60"
          Click="btnLogin_Click" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Medium" 
          BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="Blue" 
          Panel.ZIndex="1">
  </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Instead of setting grid's opacity, try setting opacity to to grid's background.

Comment: you have to set Z-Index for the controls

Comment: Thanks for your comments but i'm still stuck here is my code snippet  

<Grid Margin="0,1,0,2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="#06090b" Opacity="0.25">
<Button x:Name="btnLogin" Content="Sign in" Foreground="White" Margin="40,264,40,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Click="btnLogin_Click"
FontSize="18" FontWeight="Medium" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
Background="Blue" Panel.ZIndex="1">
</Button>
</Grid>

Comment: Thanks i got the solution @bto.rdz

Comment: <Grid Margin="0,1,0,2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color = "#06090b" Opacity="0.25"/>
            </Grid.Background>
</Grid>

Comment: @ShahidUllah Glad you did, see my answer I also added another way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

What I meant in the comment is this, you dont really need the ZIndex stuff.

you have a couple of options:

1) use an alpha color, notice background is 8 characters lenght now (first 2 are alpha, or opacity)

```
<Grid Margin="0,1,0,2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
  Background="#8006090b">
      <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Content="Sign in" Foreground="White" 
          Margin="40,264,40,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60"
          Click="btnLogin_Click" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Medium" 
          BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="Blue">
     </Button>
</Grid>
```

2) set a opacity only to the background

```
<Grid Margin="0,1,0,2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
      <Grid.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="#06090b" Opacity=".25"/>
      </Grid.Background>
      <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Content="Sign in" Foreground="White" 
          Margin="40,264,40,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60"
          Click="btnLogin_Click" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Medium" 
          BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="Blue">
     </Button>
</Grid>
```